# Kibana: Best option for performing min-max aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Given a series incoming events like say:
@timestamp1: a,b,c,d,e
@timestamp2: a,b,c,d,e
(all numbers)
I need to perform some calculation which would be of the form

```
(max (a) - min (a) )* (max (b) - min (b)) / (max © - min © ).
```

I know how to show it as a time series graph (using Visual Builder). But I also want to show it as a simple number for the overall duration that has been selected.

I tried lucene expression numeric APIs (doc[‘field_name’].max(), min()) but that doesn’t work. I didn’t see any such API within painless.

I also looked at “Scripted Metric Aggregation”, but couldn’t quite understand, where in Kibana to specify those expressions.

Same is the case with “Metrics Aggregation”, how do I make use of it within Kibana?

How can displaying aggregated number be so difficult as compared to a time-series chart? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In kibana when you create visualisation, you have in the bucket section in the bottom "advance" link, click on it, text area will open, there you can code agg that will inject to kibana aggregation, try write there your metric aggregation

Comment: Thanks for your comment Lax. I suppose you talking about the JSON Input, correct? Just to be clear, I want to get min and max of multiple fields and then do some computation on those. Is that all possible within the JSON input field?